# three.js: Is it possible to exempt an object from global clipping?

Tags: three.js

I have many textured meshes so they must have different materials. It seems like there are only two ways to clip: globally, and per-material.

However, I want some visualizers to not be clipped (e.g. the plane I'm manipulating to define the clip planes), but all of the rest of the meshes are to be clipped. So I want to use global clipping, but to exempt the parts of the 3D UI (specific objects) from clipping. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly certain that I can address this at the application level by separating the scenes so that i can issue the render of items i need clipped by using globally clipped functionality, and then clear out the clip planes and render a second scene containing UI elements prior to clearing the renderbuffers.

Comment: Using the global clip plane will clip everything that the clipping is applied to. Because it applies to the renderer i think every scene rendered with it will have the clipping applied to it. Separating the passes into different scenes is one way to go, you would clear the `myRenderer.clippingPlanes` in between. <- this might not be as clear from the answer you wrote.

Comment: It sounds like exactly what i tried to describe. Thanks.